# Find permutations of list with unique Heads

Tags: list, prolog, permutation

I have a list of unique elements, and I want to generate permutations of that list but I only want the elements to be the head of a list once, like this:

```
?- special_permutation([a,b,c], X).
X = [a,b,c] ;
X = [b,a,c] ;
X = [c,a,b] ;
false.
?- special_permutation([a,b,c,d,e], X).                                 
X = [a, b, c, d, e] ;
X = [b, a, c, d, e] ;
X = [c, a, b, d, e] ;
X = [d, a, b, c, e] ;
X = [e, a, b, c, d] ;
false.
```

(The order of the tail elements doesn't matter to me)

What I've tried so far is this:

```
test([Head|Tail], [AltHead|AltTail]) :-
    permutation([Head|Tail], [AltHead|AltTail]),
    Head \= AltHead.
```

Which returns no permutations where the head is a, but returns two permutations for b and c each.

Perhaps I need to store one permutation for each element where that element is the head, and then when new permutations are made, check if their head is not already the head of one of the permutations in that stored list?

Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or an easier method?

Comment: @repeat I've added an example with five elements. CapelliC 's answer seems to work with bigger lists as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that select/3 should do (at least this seems to match the required outcome)

```
special_permutation(L, [H|R]) :-
  select(H, L, R).
```